# Can we build an expo app with bluetooth printing facility without ejecting?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am attempting to use Bluetooth printing with a React Native Expo app in managed flow. While Expo provides `expo-print`, it does not support Bluetooth printing. Is there a way to achieve this functionality without ejecting the Expo app?

Answer (score 0):

Per Expo's latest documentation [0], the concept of 'ejecting' is deprecated:

> Yes, Expo eject is a deprecated term and is no longer necessary. It was replaced by the `npx expo prebuild` command which continuously generates native projects for you based on the libraries in your project and the app config (app.json). Learn more in the Expo Prebuild documentation.

This means that if you're on the latest version of Expo, you can implement your own custom native module to support Bluetooth printing.

[0] - https://docs.expo.dev/faq/#is-expo-eject-deprecated

Comment: Can't we make an app including bluetooth printing option in managed workflow?